# Trying to compile an old Java project but missing resources and I don't know how to include them

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

Very new to Java. I have some old code I'm looking at and I have a problem with `findbugs`. I'm using Eclipse and a regular Java project. I've installed it using the `Install new software` from the `Help` menu but now I don't know how to continue. I can see that it's added to the `.project` file too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>My Project</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.findbugsBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.findbugsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

`.classpath`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-16">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I get the below unresolved error.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have the plugin installed in your Eclipse library and that it is on the build path?

Comment: Imports would have to be something in the .classpath rather than .projects

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm for sure not sure :) How do I make sure of that?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of a jar name, using the usual naming convention for imported jars, is a reverse of the url where the jar originates. So in this case, given "edu.umd" I did a search for "umd.edu" and came to the site for the University of Maryland.

From their, using their search field, I entered keywords derived from the rest of the name: "findbugs plugin". The keyword "eclipse" would have also be a good try. The results of the search showed that UMD has [an Eclipse plugin called findbugs](https://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/).

To load a plugin, in Eclipse, on the tab "Help" select "Eclipse Marketplace". From there, enter "findbugs". The plugin that you are missing will likely be one of the first shown. I believe in this case it is called "FindBugs Eclipse Plugin 3.0.1". If you install this, the error will likely disappear.

It might be worth checking first to see if the plugin is already installed. To do this, click on the "Help" tab the "About" at the bottom. (It probably says "About Eclipse"--I'm using a variant of Eclipse so mine says "About Spring Tool Suite 4" so I can't give you the exact phrase you will see.) From the popup that appears, there should be a button "Installation Details". Click this for yet another popup and on this one, there should be a tab for "Plug-ins". Clicking this should give you a list of all your current plug-ins.

Given the elapsed time, sometimes things go stale, so you may actually have an older version of the plugin. If so, it will require updating or reinstalling. Also, depending on the age of the code you are trying to run, your code may need some modification if it's attempting to use deprecated/deleted elements of the plug-in. So you might not be totally out of the woods yet. However, Eclipse should give you the error messages needed for determining the next steps if that is the case.

But there IS a good chance adding the plug-in to your Eclipse IDE will be sufficient to get the code running again.

Comment: Fantastic reply. Gave me more insight in eclipse than days of reading almost giving up. I'll give it a go :)

Comment: Glad to help. I remember all too well my start with Eclipse, and feeling similarly frustrated with the documentation provided, and could tell you were at a similar stage. Do give the answer an "up" arrow if you think the info is helpful and may help others as well. StackOverflow is attempting to be an efficient resource for finding answers via search, and indications of solutions and useful info by its users is a major component that makes that possible.